# Deploying web2py app on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web2py

I'm tring to hosped my web2py app on GAE, but I'm not having success. I copied the web2py\example\app.example.yaml to web2py\app.yaml and the queue.yaml too. I edited the line application of the first file cited. I downloaded the web2py_src and the GAE luncher for windows, then I created a account on GAE, where my app is named 'topranchos'. The I added the app on GAE, ran one time and clicked in Deploy. It showed that the files was updated on server.

Then, when I try to access http://topranchos.appspot.com , the server raise HTTP 500 error.

How can I solve it?

The link to image of console from GAE dashboard is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAXoq.png

Comment: are you sure is not httpS?

Comment: you also need to put more info here. what do the appengine logs/console/dashboard show?

Comment: Zig Mandel, I'm sure. However the GAE accepts both the http and httpS, no?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new on hospeding :)

Comment: See the last line in your gae image. That seems to be your error. Google it.

Comment: Why my question was edited, Dmitry Sadovnychyi?

Answer (score -1):

I solved this problem moving the handlers/gaehandler.py to web2py root path. Thank you